# python asyncio add tasks dynamically

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm learning asyncio in python, I want to try something with asyncio. My goal is to read input from user continuously and use that input to create a job/task that needs to be run asynchronously.

```
import asyncio
import os
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def action():
    inp = int(input('enter: '))
    await asyncio.sleep(inp)
    os.system(f"say '{inp} seconds waited'")

async def main():
    while True:
        await asyncio.ensure_future(action())

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

I'm messing up something and I want to know how to achieve it. Every time user enters a number, script needs to sleep for given time, then speak out that it has waited. This entire thing needs to be in concurrent. if user enters 100 as input, the script should start a task to sleep for 100 seconds, but at the user side, it needs to ask for input again as soon as the user enters it.

Answer (score 5):

The main problem with your code was that you called `input()` directly in your async function. `input` itself is a blocking function and does not return until a newline or end-of-file is read. This is a problem because Python asynchronous code is still single-threaded, and if there is a blocking function, nothing else will execute. You need to use [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) in this case.

Another problem with your code, although not directly relevant to your question, was that you mixed the pre-python3.7 way of invoking an event loop and the python3.7+ way. Per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run), `asyncio.run` is used on its own. If you want to use the pre 3.7 way of invoking a loop, the correct way is

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

or

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

Since you have a `while True` in your `main()`, there's no difference between `run_until_complete` and `run_forever`.

Lastly, there is no point in using `ensure_future()` in your `main()`. The point of `ensure_future` is providing a "normal" (i.e. non-async) function a way to schedule things into the event loop, since they can't use the `await` keyword. Another reason to use `ensure_future` is if you want to schedule many tasks with high io-bounds (ex. network requests) without waiting for their results. Since you are `await`ing the function call, there is naturally no point of using `ensure_future`.

Here's the modified version:

```py
import asyncio
import os

async def action():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    inp = await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, 'Enter a number: ')
    await asyncio.sleep(int(inp))
    os.system(f"say '{inp} seconds waited'")


async def main():
    while True:
        await action()


asyncio.run(main())
```

In this version, before a user-input is entered, the code execution is alternating between `await action()` and `await loop.run_in_executor()`. When no other tasks are scheduled, the event-loop is mostly idle. However, when there are things scheduled (simulated using `await sleep()`), then the control will be naturally transferred to the long-running task that is scheduled.

One key to Python async programming is you have to ensure the control is transferred back to the event-loop once in a while so other scheduled things can be run. This happens whenever an `await` is encountered. In your original code, the interpreter get stuck at `input()` and never had a chance to go back to the event-loop, which is why no other scheduled tasks ever get executed until a user-input is provided.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So, is it not possible to achieve what I'm trying to do with asyncio?

Comment: @AjayDyavathi it is possible and I believe the modified version I posted does precisely what you asked. Maybe I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import asyncio


WORKERS = 10


async def worker(q):
    while True:
        t = await q.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        q.task_done()

        print(f"say '{t} seconds waited'")


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    tasks = []

    for _ in range(WORKERS):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(q)))

    print(f'Keep inserting numbers, "q" to quit...')

    while (number := await asyncio.to_thread(input)) != "q":
        q.put_nowait(int(number))

    await q.join()

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
Keep inserting numbers, "q" to quit...
1
say '1 seconds waited'
3
2
1
say '1 seconds waited'
say '2 seconds waited'
say '3 seconds waited'
q
```

**Note:** **Python 3.9+** required due to some new syntax (`:=`) and function (`asyncio.to_thread`) in use.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

async def aworker(q):
    ''' Worker that takes numbers from the queue and prints them '''    
    while True:
        t = await q.get() # Wait for a number to be put in the queue
        print(f"{t} received {asyncio.current_task().get_coro().__name__}:{asyncio.current_task().get_name()}")
        await asyncio.sleep(t)
        q.task_done()
        print(f"waited for {t} seconds in {asyncio.current_task().get_coro().__name__}:{asyncio.current_task().get_name()}")

async def looper():
    ''' Infinite loop that prints the current task name '''
    i = 0
    while True:
        i+=1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"{i} {asyncio.current_task().get_name()}")
        names = []
        for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
            names.append(task.get_name())
        print(names)

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    tasks = []
    
    # create two worker tasks and one infinitely looping task
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(aworker(q), name="aworker 1")) # Create a worker which handles input from the queue
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(aworker(q), name="aworker 2")) # Create another worker which handles input from the queue
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(looper(),name="looper")) # Create a looper task which prints the current task name and the other running tasks
    
    for task in tasks:
        # print the task names thus far
        print(task.get_name())

    print(f'Keep inserting numbers, "q" to quit...')
    
    ''' asyncio.thread names itself Task-1 '''
    while (number := await asyncio.to_thread(input)) != "q":
        try:
            q.put_nowait(int(number))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid number")

    await q.join()

    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).